NVidia Quadpro FX3800 driver
I have installed ubuntu 24.04 on my Dell T3500 with the above named video card.
The install gives me the nouveau driver and that does not work with the Stellarium snap application.
I started to install the driver from NVidia and it tells me that I can go to the Software Updater and find the correct driver under "Drivers".  It isn't there and the SU tells me there are no additional drivers for my machine.
Where can I get the ubuntu driver for this video card?
